# get_login_url goes to blank page when coming from naked url

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just started hosting my app on a new domain. I selected a url forwarding option with my registrar. Which seems to work. example.com didn't work before (as opposed to the subdomain www.example.com) but now it does.

The problem is that if I access the site via example.com and try to login, `users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)`, I go to a blank page. If I go to www.example.com the login works fine. In both cases `self.request.uri` is returning the www subdomain, even though in the first case example.com is still shown in the browser.

I don't really know much about this stuff. Any tips on where I should go from here?

Comment: How is your registrar "forwarding" the URL? To work correctly, it should be serving a 301 redirect, and the browser should be displaying the www address. It sounds like it might be serving the real page in a frame?

Comment: @Wooble I noticed that when using the site through example.com the url shown in the browser never changes. I can view all the pages, but instead of example.com/home/ or example.com/admin/ it just says example.com the whole time. Does that support your hypothesis?

Comment: There was a forwarding option between 'masked' and '301 redirect'. I set it to 301 and all is now good. Thanks Wooble! If you post that as an answer I'll give you the accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing the site via "example.com", `self.request.uri` is from that domain, which is the domain where the cookie is created. When it then redirects back, it goes to "www.example.com", which has no cookie, but your site is expecting a user to be logged in.

Suggestions: use a relative path like `/` (or webapp2's uri routing) instead of a full URI, or first redirect to www.example.com before doing the login.

Comment: Thanks! The only way I know to get the url from within a request handler is with `self.request.uri` and it always thinks I'm at "www.example.com". So my python scripts wouldn't know when to do the redirect. Do I need to do the redirect with javascript?(and/or)Could you elaborate a bit on how I would use a relative url here?